# Send XML data to WSDL

Tags: php, xml, wsdl

i use next code:

```
<?php
include ('class.doLogin.php');  
// xml content
$xmlDocument = '<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <mns1:doLogin xmlns:mns1="http://sphinx.dat.de/services/Authentication">
            <request>
                <customerLogin>1323863</customerLogin>
                <customerNumber>teltfran</customerNumber>
                <customerSignature>akEwRUF3TUNWeXFwazRLZlNzS3p5VE5NL3BQaXJpc1FiWW1OM0lEdGlCdjBNVmJ2RCtCSC9ma0laSEIxR3RWdQ0Kc1VHeVY3VnFTRCtiRVI1aXRhbFFoVTBaVGFNPQ0KPU1VUjg=</customerSignature>
                <interfacePartnerNumber>1323863</interfacePartnerNumber>
                <interfacePartnerSignature>jA0EAwMCoHVabOFMT5lgySuK+MYbVQs2qPAgq/QI3TpiuR3raZMh710KRctv2aPd31LmjBiWaM0WDQl0</interfacePartnerSignature>
            </request>
        </mns1:doLogin>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient(
            "http://www.dat.de:80/DATECodeSelection/services/Authentication?wsdl",
            array(
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
                'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
            )
);



$xmlvar = new SoapVar(
            '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://sphinx.dat.de/services/Authentication" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >'.$xmlDocument.'</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>',
            XSD_ANYXML
);

$doLogin = new doLogin();
$doLogin->request[0] = new doLoginRequest();
$doLogin->request[0]->customerLogin = "1323863";
$doLogin->request[1]->customerNumber = "teltfran";
$doLogin->request[2]->customerSignature = "akEwRUF3TUNWeXFwazRLZlNzS3p5VE5NL3BQaXJpc1FiWW1OM0lEdGlCdjBNVmJ2RCtCSC9ma0laSEIxR3RWdQ0Kc1VHeVY3VnFTRCtiRVI1aXRhbFFoVTBaVGFNPQ0KPU1VUjg";
$doLogin->request[3]->interfacePartnerNumber = "1323863";
$doLogin->request[4]->interfacePartnerSignature = "jA0EAwMCoHVabOFMT5lgySuK+MYbVQs2qPAgq/QI3TpiuR3raZMh710KRctv2aPd31LmjBiWaM0WDQl0";



try {
    $params->xmlDocument = (object)$xmlvar;
    //$save_result = $client->doLogin($params);
    $client->doLogin($doLogin);
    echo "<pre>\n\n";
    echo "Result :\n";
    echo "</pre>";
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
}

?>
```

and code for class.doLogin.php

```
<?php
class doLoginRequest{
    public $customerLogin;
    public $customerNumber;
    public $customerSignature;
    public $interfacePartnerNumber;
    public $interfacePartnerSignature;
}

class doLogin{
    /* array<doLoginRequest> */
   public $request;


}
?>
```

but get fault: SOAP Fault: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'customerLogin' property - where problem? how i can fix my error? if possible tell me where wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Last time I used Soap with PHP, you didn't have to construct the XML your self, you simply called `doRequest` on the client object with the method name and a list of params? - http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: yes, you right, i have xml and i need send xml structure to wsdl and receive "authorizationFailed" or "SessionID", here wsdl url: http://www.dat.de:80/DATECodeSelection/services/Authentication?wsdl, i see also 2 method, doLogin and doLoginRequest, but how fix my code, i now know

Answer (score 0):

Based on tests I've made using your example code, I also get an AuthorizationException stating that authorisation has failed.

This leads me to believe that the login details you are using are the cause, otherwise you'd be getting a completely different error if the request was malformed, for example:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'request' property
```

or

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'customerLogin' property
```

However when providing all of the required fields, i.e.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.dat.de:80/DATECodeSelection/services/Authentication?wsdl');

$tmp = new stdClass();
$tmp->request = new stdClass();
$tmp->request->customerLogin = 1323863;
$tmp->request->customerNumber = 'teltfran';
$tmp->request->customerSignature = 'akEwRUF3TUNWeXFwazRLZlNzS3p5VE5NL3BQaXJpc1FiWW1OM0lEdGlCdjBNVmJ2RCtCSC9ma0laSEIxR3RWdQ0Kc1VHeVY3VnFTRCtiRVI1aXRhbFFoVTBaVGFNPQ0KPU1VUjg';
$tmp->request->interfacePartnerNumber = 1323863;
$tmp->request->interfacePartnerSignature = 'jA0EAwMCoHVabOFMT5lgySuK+MYbVQs2qPAgq/QI3TpiuR3raZMh710KRctv2aPd31LmjBiWaM0WDQl0';

try {
    var_dump($client->doLogin($tmp));
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

You simply get an AuthorizationFailed exception, `de.dat.sphinx.global.exception.AuthorizationException: Authorization failed`

It may be worth checking with www.dat.de that your credentials are correct?